# Cause of this SwiftData memory leak?

Tags: swift, swiftui, memory-leaks, swift-data

Profiling with Xcode Leaks reveals a leak in the following code where I am trying to asynchronously fetch an array of `Cat` objects from SwiftData:

```
class SomeViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var modelContainer: ModelContainer
    var cats = [Cats]()

    func prepareCats() {
        Task.detached {
            //memory leak detected in the following line (or two)
            let bgActor = CatManager.BackgroundActor(modelContainer: self.modelContainer)
            if let cats = try await bgActor.fetchCatsFrom(vet: vet) {
                self.cats = cats
            }
        }
    }
 }



class CatManager {
    
    static let shared: CatManager = CatManager()
    private init() {}
    
    @ModelActor
    actor BackgroundActor {

        func fetchCatsFrom(vet: Vet) async throws -> [Cat]? {
            var vetFetchDescriptor = FetchDescriptor<Vet>()
            let vetId = vet.id
            vetFetchDescriptor.predicate = #Predicate<Vet> { $0.id == vetId }
            
            guard let vet = try modelContext.fetch(vetFetchDescriptor).first else {
                print("vet not found")
                return nil
            }
            let filteredCats = vet.cats.filter { !$0.homed }
            return filteredCats
            
        }
    }
}
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong here and how to resolve the memory leak?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75709573/why-does-taskc-error-work-even-though-c-is-a-class-which-is-not-sendable/75713017#75713017

Comment: This has been discussed [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78051882/swiftdata-leaks).

Comment: @JoakimDanielson so there's no solution?

Comment: I think it's something Apple needs to fix. And at least when I measured the leak it was quite small so I can live with it for now.

Comment: Usually view model objects are the source of leaks because you are supposed to use the View struct for your view data Also, in SwiftUi it is .task not Task{} for async/await with correct life time.